# Create a .tar.bz2 file given an array of files

Tags: bash, shell, tar, bz2

In a `Bash` script, I have an array that contains a list of files (in the form of their complete file paths):

```
declare -a individual_files=("/path/to/a" "/path/to/b" "/path/to/c")
```

I want to create a compressed file in `tar.bz2` which contains all the files in the array, using `tar` command.

So far, I have tried

```
tar rf files.tar "${individual_files[@]}"
tar cjf files.tar.bz2 files.tar
```

But for some reason, `files.tar.bz2` always contains the last file in the array only.

What is the correct command(s) for doing so, preferably without creating the intermediate `.tar` file?

UPDATED: using @PanRuochen's answer, this is what I see in the verbose info:

```
+ tar cfvj /Users/skyork/test.tar.bz2 /Users/skyork/.emacs /Users/skyork/.Rprofile /Users/skyork/.aspell.en.pws /Users/skyork/.bash_profile /Users/skyork/.vimrc /Users/skyork/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
tar: Removing leading '/' from member names 
a Users/skyork/.emacs
a Users/skyork/.Rprofile
a Users/skyork/.aspell.en.pws
a Users/skyork/.bash_profile
a Users/skyork/.vimrc
a Users/skyork/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
```

<del>But still, the resulted `test.tar.bz2` file has only the last file of the array (`/Users/skyork/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist`) in it.</del>

My bad, the files are indeed there but hidden.

Comment: Add `set -x` before the `tar rf` command and add the `v` flag to the `rf` command and see what you get as output?

Comment: Why do you think that the tar file is incorrect? All the files in the archive *except* the .plist file are hidden, so you won't see them if you unpack the archive and then do `ls`; you need  `ls -a` to see hidden files. (Hidden files have names starting with a `.`. Probably your Mac finder also hides them from you.) Other than that, the answer by @PanRouchen is correct, although I would personally leave out the `v` because it just pollutes stdout. (Useful for verifying that things are working, I guess.)

Comment: Your tar has all the files. It's just that the files beginning with `.` are hidden.

Comment: Sorry guys, that's a stupid question from me. Of course, I was checking the files in Finder, which does not show hidden files by default

Comment: Nah, the only stupid questions are the ones from which you learn nothing. And while you may not have learned much about tar with this one, you've certainly learned something! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tar cfvj files.tar.bz2 "${individual_files[@]}"
```

`v` should give you verbose information about how bz2 file is created.